# How to restructure a horizontal dataset to vertical by omitting missing values

Tags: r

My dataframe dat looks like one below:

```
PatID     X1       X2     X3     X4     X5    X6      X7       X8
  1       0.8288 0.7920 0.7552 0.6447   NA    NA      NA       NA
  2       0.9500 0.9500 0.9500 0.9139 0.8092  NA      NA       NA
  3        NA      NA     NA     NA     NA    NA      NA       NA
  4        0.9500 0.9100  0.8092 NA     NA    NA      NA       NA
```

I wanted to make it like one below:

```
PatID   Score
1       0.8388
1       0.7920
1       0.7552
1       0.6447
2       0.9500
2       0.9500
2       0.9500
2       0.9139
2       0.8092
4       0.9500
4       0.9100
4       0.8092
```

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then edit and rephrase the question.  [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  What have you tried.  This is a wide-to-long transformation, then drop NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `melt` in `reshape2`:

```
new_df <- melt(df, id.vars = 'PatID', na.rm = TRUE)
new_df[order(new_df$PatID),]
```

Output:

```
   PatID variable  value
1      1       X1 0.8288
5      1       X2 0.7920
9      1       X3 0.7552
13     1       X4 0.6447
2      2       X1 0.9500
6      2       X2 0.9500
10     2       X3 0.9500
14     2       X4 0.9139
18     2       X5 0.8092
4      4       X1 0.9500
8      4       X2 0.9100
12     4       X3 0.8092
```